# How to tell if a website offers AJAX services

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been studding AJAX and think I understand what I need to do my assignment.  I want to get gold and silver prices from a website, but how do I know what website will support my AJAX request? I will use http://www.monex.com/liveprices/ for an example. Do I put this website's URL in my code or is there a secret URL that I need?

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.monex.com/liveprices/", true);
```

When I try this, I get the following error message.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked:
    The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.monex.com/liveprices/.
        (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Is it possible that this website does not offer AJAX support, and if so how do I know what website do and do not offer AJAX support?  Thank you.

Comment: Usually a website will offer a RESTful API which will be free for small queries but may end up costing you a monthly fee for faster transactions. See if the site offers an API. If it does not, you may have to ask them, for permission, if you can scrape their page. If you only need to do this once a day, I think you can go ahead and just scrape it with a server script, using python or PHP and storing the data locally on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a website will offer a RESTful API which will be free for small queries but may end up costing you a monthly fee for faster transactions. See if the site offers an API. If it ***does not***, you may have to ***ask them, for permission***, if you can scrape their page. If you only need to do this once a day, I think you can go ahead and just scrape it with a server script, using python or PHP and storing the data locally on your server.

If you do scrape their page, don't spam requests because it will increase bandwidth on their end and cause them to ban your IP or anyone else using your website.

I found a question on Quora asking, [***"What is a good (free) API for getting the current price of gold?"***](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-free-API-for-getting-the-current-price-of-gold). There are several APIs mentioned in the responses. I am sure that you can find one that you like.

Here are the links, listed by popularity, that are mentioned on that page:

- https://www.quandl.com/data/BUNDESBANK/BBK01_WT5511-Gold-Price-USD
- http://www.gold-feed.com
- http://drayah.no.de/metals/latest
- http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~rysun/goldprice
- http://goldseek.com
- http://www.kitco.com

I am sure that there are more, just do some more research.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that this website does not offer AJAX support

Most people do not configure their sites to provide cross-origin Ajax support because:

- They have to turn it on explicitly (i.e. it is work for them)
- It probably wouldn't benefit them
- It will cost them (bandwidth use without visits to their pages)
- It would leak user's private information if they had a login facility

> if so how do I know what website do and do not offer AJAX support?

If they do then they will generally supply developer documentation that tells you how to access their APIs. So look for developer documentation on their site.